Older R version dmg file
Where can I get R 4.4.0 dmg installation file for Mac? Im only able to find the tar.gz files on R website.

R isn’t packaged in DMG format but in PKG format. In general, the easiest way of installing specific R versions on macOS is via rig.

Just figured it out from the URL-https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/base/
Not able to add the above as an answer for some reason, though.

It depends on your machine's architecture. From https://cran.r-project.org/:

arm64 / Apple silicon: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/
Intel-based: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/

